Is it possible to find the length of the x line?
For start, ill give a contex of what I am trying to do.
I am coding a script that placing stiching via parallel to a trace line (I known its coordinates). Vias are the circles of known diameter "O1", "O2" you will see on my problem below. Stiching vias look like that. The curve is made from straight segments thats where the line "2" comes in my problem.
So for my problem, The lines "1" and "2" are parallel to the trace, and I known every points on them(I calculated them for the traces coordinates). So the length of the lines "1" and "2", the distance from the trace, "a",are known and also I hopefully can calculate the slope of the two lines so i can find the Φ angle, and the distance "c".
The problem is that when I place the last via on the line "1", I want to add an offset to where I will place the via in the line "2". (there is also a little offset because the two circles don't meet on the line "2" but I think will add it manually with trial and error.)
In the images below, the first image is the simplified problem, and the second image is with auxiliary lines drawn.
Thank you for your time.
UPDATED. Added context and better explanation and images:
Image1
Image2

With this information, no. Unless you know more about where that angle phi lies, and on what line. At the moment you just have a random isosceles triangle floating around the center.

@RobinSparrow The angle $\phi$ determines how far is the vertex from $O$, so it's possible to find $x$.

@RobinSparrow i updated the image. my bad... the triangle and the angle phi is formed by expanding the two lines

Is the triangle with the angle $\phi$ an isosceles triangle? Anyone solving this problem would greatly benefit from a more precise drawing.

@MJT i honestly don't know if it is isosceles... but I am sure the angle ϕ is known because the two straight lines forming are known.

It's not at all clear what the letters c and a refer to.  Is the triangle an isoceles triangle with sides b,a and a?  If so what role do the squares serve?  I don't see how x can be fixed.  we can just slid the vertex $\phi$ as far as we want to the right and have the triangles and squares move along for the ride and we can get x to be a close as we like to zero.

@fleablood a is the lines that start from the same point, to the line tha form right angle.the square is just to show there are right angles.

@jjagmath: I'm not following. The initial diagram differed from the present diagram, if you looked closely the phi angle was not on any particular line of the drawing (i.e., the right angles were irrelevant to it), it was just some random closure of a quadrilateral on the base of the isosceles, I don't see how it could be solved in that form.

@RobinSparrow yeah that is more correct representation of my problem. sorry for the initial drawing

@arisk4: GeoGebra is a free program that many here use for geometry drawings and also much basic algebra, I would suggest you check it out, you would be able to make a nice diagram within a few minutes and people here would be able to give you better help.

You need to include that the lines of the isoceles triangle are perpendicular to the displayed lines. If they aren't  (or at a fixed angle) we can rotate the isosceles triangle while keeping $c$ and $\phi$ fixed (so the vertex of $\phi$ will slide) and change the value of $x$.  But if the angles of the lines of length $b$ are fixed... we can't and everything is fixed.

Move left from $O$ a distance $b$ to point $P$ (not marked). Move distance $a$ along the perpendicular from $P$. Draw the circle with radius $a$ centered at the point you reach. Find the point where the chord of length $c$ from $P$ meets that circle (that's the intersection of with the circle of radius $b$ at $P$). Draw the tangent at that point and find the distance along the tangent to the original circle of radius $r$.
The algebra should be tedious but straightforward.
The small triangle with vertex angle $\varphi$ will have to be isosceles since it's formed by two tangents and a chord. The angle $\varphi$ is determined - it can't be separately specified.

i updated the drawing if that helps

See my edits. You keep changing the labels, and the problem itself. In particular, you removed the two right angles. You can specify either the second right angle or $\varphi$.

If both right angles are required then I think this answer solves your problem.
